# How to create a dynamic route in Next.js

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

How can I create this type of url :

http://localhost:3000/designer/book1

http://localhost:3000/engeniring/book1

http://localhost:3000/art/book1

If I try to put files in specific name in pages folder, Then I have to do that multiple time.

Any idea?

Here desinger, enginerring, art are dynamic like book category and book1 are also dynamic is act like a single post

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could set up the folder structure for nested dynamic routes**

Something like this:

[image]

And then have your nesting routes inside.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vristt) is a live example for that

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will give it a try

Comment: Can I use it, by fatching the category and books via database? @Ryan Le

Comment: Yes, you can. They are only dynamic params of the URL, it accepts params by the format in the folder structure. Take a closer look at the example, you can easily imagine how things work

Comment: Routing is working fine, But whenever it change the whole website gets refreshed, that will call an API again and again